# P not non-negative $\rightarrow$ we can assign its variables to rational numbers and get a negative answer

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, rational-numbers

By definition, a (multivariate) polynomial P is non-negative if for every real value we assign to the variables, the result is not negative. For instance, $P=a^2+b^2-2ab=(a-b)^2$ is non-negative.

Using this information, how can I prove that if P is **not** non-negative then there is a way we can assign its variables to **rational** numbers and get a negative answer?

P not being non-negative implies that there is a selection of **real** values that causes it to be negative, but how can I prove that there exists a choice of **rational** numbers that also results in a negative value?

Thanks!

Comment: How about the fact that a polynomial is continuous, so it must be negative in a whole neighbourhood around the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on a suggestion in the comments, suppose that $P $ is negative when the variables $x_1, \cdots, x_i $ take the values $a_1, \cdots, a_i $. Then, because $P $ is continuous, there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that the polynomial on $a_1 + \epsilon, \cdots, a_i + \epsilon $ is **still** negative (it has not changed signs). Then, because "there are a heck lot of rationals", there is, for each $j $, a rational between $a_j $ and $a_j + \epsilon $. Making the variables assume those values, the polynomial is *still* negative for those values.